# BGAppRefreshTaskRequest completes before network request is completed

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, swiftui, background-task

I need to perform a DB insert into MongoDB Atlas using a scheduled background task in SwiftUI. Unfortunately, at the last step when I actually perform the insert, the request never resolves leading to a insert failure.

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: SwiftUI.App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
            // ...
            case .background:
                scheduleAppRefresh()
            // ...
            }
        }
        .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("pushData")) {
            if let realmApp = realmApp {
                guard let user = realmApp.currentUser else {
                    return
                }
                let client = user.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
                let database = client.database(named: "ExampleDB")
                let collection = database.collection(withName: "Activities")

                let height: Document = ["activityKey": "height", "startDate": AnyBSON(Date()), "endDate": AnyBSON(Date()), "value": 1.9, "unit": "m"]

                await addActivityToMongo(height: height, collection: collection)
            }
        }
    }

    func addActivityToMongo(height: Document, collection: RealmSwift.MongoCollection) async {
        print("Inserting into MongoDB")
        do {
            let objectId = try await collection.insertOne(height)
            print("Successfully inserted a document with id: \(objectId)")
        } catch {
            print("Error writing to MongoDB: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let backgroundTask = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "pushData")
        backgroundTask.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
        try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(backgroundTask)
        print("Successfully scheduled a background task")
    }
}
```

I have added `pushData` to Info.plist under `Permitted background task scheduler identifiers` and the `backgroundTask` runs successfully but `await collection.insertOne(height)` never resolves - Xcode output just shows `Inserting into MongoDB` which I have printed until I bring the app again to the foreground at which point it fails with

```
ERROR: The network connection was lost.
Call to MongoDB failed: The network connection was lost
Marking simulated task complete: <BGAppRefreshTask: pushData>
```

Is there something that I am missing to actually make this work?

Comment: @Rob I actually followed the reference video that u sent at first and called `scheduleAppRefresh` in the `.backgroundTask` modifier but nothing happens when I put the app in the background - app does not trigger the breakpoint like it should after `BGTaskScheduler.share.submit(task)`. And yes I use `_simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier` to launch the background task.

Comment: That is why I had to go back to the `scenePhase` technique which other tutorials usually describe for scheduling these background tasks

Comment: @Rob can u explain a bit more how can I do that in a SwiftUI lifecycle app. I understand you are talking about
`BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "pushData", using: nil) { task in
     self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
}`
But its unclear to me how would I use that in a SwiftUI app. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252670/discussion-between-rob-and-m-umar).

Answer (score 0):

You likely need a `BGProcessingTaskRequest` so you can set `requiresNetworkConnectivity` to `true`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtaskrequest

`scheduleAppRefresh` should change to something like

```
    let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "pushData")
    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
    request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
    try? BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
```

Make sure you adjust your Info.plist too

> If you’re using BGAppRefreshTask, select ”Background fetch.“

> If you’re using BGProcessingTask, select ”Background processing.“

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app

[image]

> BGProcessingTask
> A time-consuming processing task that runs while the app is in the background.